# Не работает код по событию "oninput"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно , чтоб при изменении поля `input`  выполнялась любая  функция.

Как я понял за изменение текстового поля отвечает событие `oninput`.

Проблема в том, что код  после события `oninput` не работает.

Пробовал так :

```
$("#enter").oninput(function () {   
    alert("чтот получилось")    
 })
```

и так :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var input = document.getElementById('enter');
     input.oninput = function() {
    console.log("ghbdtn")
    console.log(input)  
 }});
```

Возможно можно решить как-то по другому ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет такого события в JQuery, лист доступных событий  для форм: [ссылка](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/)!
Для событий мыши:[ссылка](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/)!

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery есть событие .change(). 
В вашей ситуации, думаю, оно необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

Это же jQuery!

```
$("#enter").on('input', function () {
```

Но вообще, вряд ли тебе нужно именно это событие.